# Firestore ConnectionState is in Waiting state forever in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to fetch records from the Firestore database and show it in the Flutter app.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Hello'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.list), onPressed: _pushSaved)
          ]),
      drawer: _buildDrawer(),
      body: _buildCarpoolsList(),
    );
  }

Widget _buildCarpoolsList() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection("carpools").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            var _carpools = snapshot.data.documents;
            return ListView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                children: _deserializeCarpools(_carpools));
          }
        });
  }
```

In the `_buildCarpoolsList()` function the `snapshot.ConnectionState` is always `ConnectionState.waiting`, and the function returns `CircularProgressBar()`.
[image: ConnectionState.waiting]

I have got a collection `carpools` in the FireStore database with a few records in it.

I have set the firestore database rules to allow all.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /** {
      allow read, write: if true;
  }
}
```

Edit: My Firebase authentication works. (If that helps)

What could be missing here?

Comment: Dumb question -> did you download the `google_services.json` file and add it to your project?

Comment: Yes, I did.
And I am working on iOS emulator.

Comment: I just saw that for iOS you need a different file: https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore, GoogleService-Info.plist. Did you that as well?

Comment: Yes, I do. It is added to my iOS app and the firebase app gets configured correctly.

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You may revise security settings in `Firebase` console.
If you created the database in production mode (not testing), it comes with security rules that might block any connection until you allow so.

Open the `Rules` tab in the database screen, (JUST TO TEST -> Make allow read, write; as below )
If it works, just consider reading about the security rules and set it appropriately as per your needs.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `GoogleService-Info.plist` in your `Runner.xcworkspace` , you must open it with Xcode. I always forget to add it in new project :

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same situation. Using cloud_firestore plugin and StreamBuilder :

```
class DealerWorkPage extends StatelessWidget {
final String wheelId;
DealerWorkPage(this.wheelId);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('wheels').document(this.wheelId).snapshots(),

    builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
        if(asyncSnapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${asyncSnapshot.error}');

        switch (asyncSnapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none: return Center(child: Text('No data'));
          case ConnectionState.waiting: return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          case ConnectionState.active:
            return Center(child: Text(asyncSnapshot["description"]))
          break;
        }
        return null;
    });
 }
}
```

**This code runs with no error**, but only showing CircularProgressIndicator() forever!

I tried another flutter project that has an add clause like :

```
await _firestore.collection('messages').add({
    'text': messageController.text,
    'from': widget.user.email,
    'date': DateTime.now().toIso8601String().toString(),
  });
```

And it throws : PlatformException(Error performing setData, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permission

Now, just like @MSaudi said, this error has something todo with firebase security rules. I then check the database security rules in Firebase Console. Yes I forget to 'extend' the date for database access :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {

// This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
// all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
// started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
// leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
// requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
//
// Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
// your app will lose access to your Firestore database
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 1, 27);
  }
 }
}
```

AFTER changing the request.time  timestamp.date(2020, 1, 27) to later date, 
**VOILA! my StreamBuilder behaves as expected!. No more waiting forever!**
I hope this information helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, I was following the guides from Flutter In focus. The state was always connecting and no data was returned and also no error. This was in iOS and then I ran the app in Android and fortunately in the LogCat, I saw a message `permission to listen to query was denied` 
by default the security rules seem to deny everything, you. have to allow it as @MSaudi mentioned. I added this and it worked

```
   match /{collectionName}/{documentId} {
       allow read, write : if collectionName == "products";
   }
```

To play with security rules, the below link will help

[Firebase security rules](https://medium.com/@khreniak/cloud-firestore-security-rules-basics-fac6b6bea18e)

Answer (score 0):

If you reviewed the [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes) on FlutterFire, and there was no issue with the security rules, check whether you use `.map()` or `.forEach()` correctly.

For example, the following is working well:

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

        List<String> urls = [];
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return ...
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return ...
        }
        
        **snapshot.data.docs.forEach((QueryDocumentSnapshot document) {
          print(document);
          urls.add(...);
        });**

        return Container( 
          child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: ...,
            childAspectRatio: (...),
            children: List.generate(urls.length, (index) {
```

However, the below example does nothing, if your widget was supposed to show some images using an item in the `urls`:

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

        List<String> urls = [];
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return ...
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return ...
        }
        
        
        **snapshot.data.docs.map((QueryDocumentSnapshot document) {
          print(document);
          urls.add(...);
        });**

        return Container( 
          child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: ...,
            childAspectRatio: (...),
            children: List.generate(urls.length, (index) {
```

While `document` is printed in both examples, it does not mean that they do the same thing. It is also worth noting that the condition `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting` is satisfied at least one time during the loading, and it makes you think that you are waiting permanently.